# Java HTTP POST request with json body from curl

Tags: java, json, http, curl, http-post

I'm trying to convert this **curl** command:

```
curl -v -s -X POST $OS_AUTH_URL/auth/tokens?nocatalog   -H "Content-Type: application/json"   -d '{ "auth": { "identity": { "methods": ["password"],"password": {"user": {"domain": {"name": "'"$OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME"'"},"name": "'"$OS_USERNAME"'", "password": "'"$OS_PASSWORD"'"} } }, "scope": { "project": { "domain": { "name": "'"$OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME"'" }, "name":  "'"$OS_PROJECT_NAME"'" } } }}'
```

Into a Java code. I saw something around but I can't to fix.
I try with a code like this but probably i'm doing some errors.

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.107:5000/v3/auth/tokens?nocatalog ");
String json = "'{ \"auth\": { \"identity\": { \"methods\": [\"password\"],\"password\": {\"user\": {\"domain\": {\"name\": \"'\"Default\"'\"},\"name\": \"'\"admin\"'\", \"password\": \"'\"MYPASSWORD\"'\"} } }, \"scope\": { \"project\": { \"domain\": { \"name\": \"'\"default\"'\" }, \"name\":  \"'\"admin\"'\" } } }}'";
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

Comment: You should probably remove the single quotes from your `json` string variable.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: You have more issues with your `json` var (with single quotes that were around shell variables). Try fixing it, it should be a valid JSON. Or, built that JSON string in Java, serializing the appropriate object.

Comment: Try with `json = "{\"auth\": {\"identity\": {\"methods\": [\"password\"], \"password\": {\"user\": {\"domain\": {\"name\": \"OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME\"}, \"name\": \"OS_USERNAME\", \"password\": \"OS_PASSWORD\"}}}, \"scope\": {\"project\": {\"domain\": {\"name\": \"OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME\"}, \"name\": \"OS_PROJECT_NAME\"}}}}"` (replacing values as appropriate).